# PrimeFaces TabView + Layout: weird behavior

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, firebug

I'm using the latest PrimeFaces (3.6-SNAPSHOT). Testing on Firefox.

I've been trying to isolate the problem. Here is what I found out.

My page design is as follows: a [TabView](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabview.jsf) - each of its tabs contains another TabView, which each of its tabs contains a [Layout](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutElement.jsf).

The problem is that on some tabs, the layout does not appear. When I compile with PrimeFaces 3.4.2 the missing layouts do not show regardless of if I click on another tabs and then click back on the tabs with the missing layout. But when I compile with PrimeFaces 3.6-SNAPSHOT if I do that (click on another tabs and then click back on the tabs with the missing layout) - the missing layout appears. Crazy, huh?

The real crazy thing is that when I see that layout is invisible, I check it with firebug and see that its HTML is different than when it does show....

How could that be?? I thought I'm getting a static page (with some Javascript, but still no change to the HTML itself). This is beyond my comprehension.

For example, restart Firefox, load the page and try to click the tabs in the following order:
(1,1) (1,2) (1,3) (1,4) all well.
Now click on tab 2 (header).
Do you see layout in tab (2,1) is gone?
Now click on (2,2) and back on (2,1) - now the layout is there.
Weird stuff.

Any idea what is going on?

It might be related to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978438/primefaces-layout-not-working-inside-tabview

Here is the code, you might want to try it out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>
<h:body>

    <p:tabView id="tabView">  

        <p:tab id="tab1" title="Godfather Part I">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                <p:graphicImage id="tab1Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg" />  
                <h:outputText id="tab1Text"  
                    value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding.  
                    His beloved son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. T  
                    hrough Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family, kind and benevolent to those who give respect,  
                    but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family." />  
            </h:panelGrid> 

            <p:tabView id="tabView1">  

                <p:tab id="tab1" title="Godfather Part I">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab1Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab1Text"  
                            value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding.  
                            His beloved son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. T  
                            hrough Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family, kind and benevolent to those who give respect,  
                            but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family." />  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (1,1)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout1">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>  

                <p:tab id="tab2" title="Godfather Part II">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab2Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab2Text" value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary continuation and sequel to his landmark 1972 film, The_Godfather, parallels the young Vito Corleone's rise with his son Michael's spiritual fall, deepening The_Godfather's depiction of the dark side of the American dream.  
                        In the early 1900s, the child Vito flees his Sicilian village for America after the local Mafia kills his family. Vito struggles to make a living, legally or illegally, for his wife and growing brood in Little Italy,  
                        killing the local Black Hand Fanucci after he demands his customary cut of the tyro's business. With Fanucci gone, Vito's communal stature grows."/>  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (1,2)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout2">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>  

                <p:tab id="tab3" title="Godfather Part III">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab3Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab3Text" value="After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.  
                            Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate."/>  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (1,3)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout3">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="tab4" title="Godfather Part IV">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab3Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab3Text" value="After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.  
                            Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate."/>  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (1,4)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout4">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>  

            </p:tabView>

        </p:tab>  

        <p:tab id="tab2" title="Godfather Part II">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                <p:graphicImage id="tab2Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg" />  
                <h:outputText id="tab2Text" value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary continuation and sequel to his landmark 1972 film, The_Godfather, parallels the young Vito Corleone's rise with his son Michael's spiritual fall, deepening The_Godfather's depiction of the dark side of the American dream.  
                In the early 1900s, the child Vito flees his Sicilian village for America after the local Mafia kills his family. Vito struggles to make a living, legally or illegally, for his wife and growing brood in Little Italy,  
                killing the local Black Hand Fanucci after he demands his customary cut of the tyro's business. With Fanucci gone, Vito's communal stature grows."/>  
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:tabView id="tabView2">  

                <p:tab id="tab1" title="Godfather Part I">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab1Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab1Text"  
                            value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding.  
                            His beloved son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. T  
                            hrough Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family, kind and benevolent to those who give respect,  
                            but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family." />  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (2,1)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout1">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>  

                <p:tab id="tab2" title="Godfather Part II">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab2Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab2Text" value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary continuation and sequel to his landmark 1972 film, The_Godfather, parallels the young Vito Corleone's rise with his son Michael's spiritual fall, deepening The_Godfather's depiction of the dark side of the American dream.  
                        In the early 1900s, the child Vito flees his Sicilian village for America after the local Mafia kills his family. Vito struggles to make a living, legally or illegally, for his wife and growing brood in Little Italy,  
                        killing the local Black Hand Fanucci after he demands his customary cut of the tyro's business. With Fanucci gone, Vito's communal stature grows."/>  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (2,2)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout2">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>  

                <p:tab id="tab3" title="Godfather Part III">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab3Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab3Text" value="After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.  
                            Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate."/>  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (2,3)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout3">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="tab4" title="Godfather Part IV">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab3Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab3Text" value="After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.  
                            Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate."/>  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (2,4)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout4">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>  

            </p:tabView>

        </p:tab>  

        <p:tab id="tab3" title="Godfather Part III">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                <p:graphicImage id="tab3Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />  
                <h:outputText id="tab3Text" value="After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.  
                    Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate."/>  
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:tabView id="tabView3">  

                <p:tab id="tab1" title="Godfather Part I">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab1Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab1Text"  
                            value="The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding.  
                            His beloved son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. T  
                            hrough Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family, kind and benevolent to those who give respect,  
                            but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family." />  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (3,1)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout1">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>  

                <p:tab id="tab2" title="Godfather Part II">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab2Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather2.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab2Text" value="Francis Ford Coppola's legendary continuation and sequel to his landmark 1972 film, The_Godfather, parallels the young Vito Corleone's rise with his son Michael's spiritual fall, deepening The_Godfather's depiction of the dark side of the American dream.  
                        In the early 1900s, the child Vito flees his Sicilian village for America after the local Mafia kills his family. Vito struggles to make a living, legally or illegally, for his wife and growing brood in Little Italy,  
                        killing the local Black Hand Fanucci after he demands his customary cut of the tyro's business. With Fanucci gone, Vito's communal stature grows."/>  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (3,2)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout2">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>  

                <p:tab id="tab3" title="Godfather Part III">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab3Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab3Text" value="After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.  
                            Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate."/>  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (3,3)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout3">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="tab4" title="Godfather Part IV">  
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  
                        <p:graphicImage id="tab3Img" value="/images/godfather/godfather3.jpg" />  
                        <h:outputText id="tab3Text" value="After a break of more than 15 years, director Francis Ford Coppola and writer Mario Puzo returned to the well for this third and final story of the fictional Corleone crime family.  
                            Two decades have passed, and crime kingpin Michael Corleone, now divorced from his wife Kay has nearly succeeded in keeping his promise that his family would one day be completely legitimate."/>  
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    Layout (3,4)

                    <p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:200px;" id="layout4">  
                        <p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="true" size="100" minSize="40" maxSize="200">  
                            West  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  

                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">  
                            Center  
                        </p:layoutUnit>  
                    </p:layout>

                </p:tab>  

            </p:tabView>

        </p:tab>  

    </p:tabView>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you can put `<p:layout>` inside a `<p:tabView>` :P. Many components just don't work together in certain combination.

Comment: Where is it documented? A layout is not supposed to use the whole page (you can see it in the showcase). The thing about components is that you can nest them however you want, since a `div` does not care what `div`s it contains. And you do see that it works with many layouts, but not with all. Also I cannot explain how the html correct itself simply by me clicking on tabs....

Comment: "It's not a bug, it's an undocumented feature." :)